# How to check if a table exists in Informix

Tags: table, metadata, informix, system-tables

What would be the query to check that a table exists in Informix ?

Answer (score 3):

To check whether an Informix table exists, use the following query:

```
SELECT       COUNT(*) 
       FROM  systables 
       WHERE tabname = 'yourtablename';
```

If the result **is not 0**, then the **table exists**.

Comment: This is the simple answer and it works fine in most databases as long as you're not using trick names (ones that need DELIMIDENT set in the environment) and you specify the table name in lower-case letters.  If your database is MODE ANSI, you might get back an answer bigger than one; in those databases, the combination of owner and tablename is unique.  Dealing with "what is the TabID of a given table name" is trickier, in general, because of these complexities.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thank you for comment. The database was not MODE ANSI. This answer worked. :)